# How to integrate cropperjs in a laravel 10 livewire 2 project without controller but component

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-10, cropperjs

I want to integrate cropperjs into a laravel 10 livewire 2 project.

I followed a tutorial and everything works fine.

But I want to remove the controller and the POST route and integrate the code into a livewire component to obtain the same result.

My first view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Laravel 9 Crop Image Before Upload Using Cropper JS - CodingSeeker</title>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/cropper.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/cropper.js') }}"></script>

    @livewireStyles

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #f6d352;
    }

    h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .preview {
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 160px;
        height: 160px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    input {
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .section {
        margin-top: 150px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 50px 30px;
    }

    .modal-lg {
        max-width: 1000px !important;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <livewire:cropimage /> 
    
@livewireScripts

</body>

</html>
```

The livewire component cropimage :

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2 section text-center">
                <h2>Laravel 9 Crop Image Before Upload Using Cropper JS - CodingSeeker</h2>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">How to crop image before upload image in laravel 9 CodingSeeker</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="img-container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <img id="image" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/3456749">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="preview"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="crop">Crop</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $modal = $('#modal');
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var cropper;

    $("body").on("change", ".image", function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        var done = function(url) {
            image.src = url;
            $modal.modal('show');
        };

        var reader;
        var file;
        var url;

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            file = files[0];

            if (URL) {
                done(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            } else if (FileReader) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    done(reader.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    });

    $modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        cropper = new Cropper(image, {
            aspectRatio: 0,
            viewMode: 3,
            preview: '.preview'
        });
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
    });

    $("#crop").click(function() {
        canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
            width: 160,
            height: 160,
        });

        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                var base64data = reader.result;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "crop-image-upload-ajax",
                    data: {
                        '_token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
                        'image': base64data
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $modal.modal('hide');
                        alert("Crop image successfully uploaded");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

my web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () { return view('crop-image-upload');});

Route::post('crop-image-upload-ajax', [CropImageController::class, 'cropImageUploadAjax']);
```

my controller

```
class CropImageController extends Controller
{


    public function cropImageUploadAjax(Request $request)
    {
        $folderPath = public_path('upload/');

        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->image);
        $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

        $imageName = uniqid() . '.png';

        $imageFullPath = $folderPath . $imageName;

        file_put_contents($imageFullPath, $image_base64);

        $saveFile = new Image;
        $saveFile->description = 'description';
        $saveFile->name = $imageName;
        $saveFile->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Crop Image Uploaded Successfully']);
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner so it's difficult for me to do it without help...

I've done a lot of research on google, chatgpt and googlebard but nothing is conclusive.